# Detect when burn-in protection has activated?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I can check to see if the burn-in protection property is enabled, but is there a way to tell when burn-in mode is currently active? Like specifically when the screen shifts.

Basically something like "onAmbientModeChanged" for burn in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In an **activity**, extend `WearableActivity` and override `onEnterAmbientMode`, you have in parameter a Bundle where you can retrieve the property wanted.
(check this [WearableActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html))

```
@Override
public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
    super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
    boolean burnIn = ambientDetails.getBoolean(EXTRA_BURN_IN_PROTECTION);
    boolean lowBit = ambientDetails.getBoolean(EXTRA_LOWBIT_AMBIENT);
}
```

In a **CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine**, override `onPropertiesChanged` :

```
@Override
    public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
        super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
        boolean lowBit = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);
        boolean burnIn = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION, false);
    }
```

Override `onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAMbientMode)`, it is called whenever the watchface switches from interactive to ambient mode and vice versa :

```
@Override
    public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
        super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
        if (mState.isAmbient() != inAmbientMode) {
            mState.setAmbient(inAmbientMode);
            //make your updates on your drawing parameters if needed
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is for a watchface, so it'd be in the CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine. I just tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. I believe that only checks to see if the property itself is changed; it does not seem to fire when burn-in mode actually activates.

Comment: It's normally called when the watchface is started and it represents the system properties. The burn in protection is not a mode, it's a property of your watch's screen that has the consequences to constraint you on the ambient mode display. What do you mean by it doesn't work ?

Comment: While debugging, I put a break point on `boolean burnIn = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION, false);` and then observed as the watchface shifted itself. The break point was not triggered. That's what I'm looking for here - something that actively tells me when the watch face shifts.

Comment: Oh, then you're looking for `onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAMbientMode)`, i'll edit my answer

Comment: `onAmbientModeChanged` only seems to fire when the screen goes in or out of ambient mode. What I meant by "screen shifts" is when the whole screen is moved by a pixel or two to prevent burn in. Is there something that triggers the moment that happens?

Comment: Sorry, i totally misunderstood your question, if there is i don't know it, i've looked at the CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine and its super classes callbacks but nothing seems to fit, what do you want to do (just curiosity) ?

Comment: That's alright, thanks for trying anyway! I'm drawing very thin arcs for calendar events on the edge of the watch face. Obviously this poses a problem when the face decides to shift. I could permanently move them inward, but I very much prefer the look of them on the edges. I was thinking I could try actively moving them inward when the watch face shifts itself, and moving them back to the edge when coming out of ambient mode.

Comment: yes, sure, moving them inward just on ambient mode would be the best, and since everything else is black in ambient mode, it won't be so obvious that it's not right at the edge of the screen

Comment: Yeah I might try that out. Thanks!